# Why is “underhaul” not listed in dictionaries?

Tags: dictionaries

“underhaul” is not listed in dictionaries.

Did I spell it wrong? Or is it slang?

Comment: Can you give examples, or quote a published work or internet source where it's used in a clear sense?

Comment: Are you claiming that it appears in no dictionaries?

Comment: I thought it might have been in the Urban Dictionary, but it isn't.

Comment: Sounds like a direct syllable translation from Dutch Onderhoud - I have only ever heard of overhaul

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a non-accepted word.

Comment: What's it supposed to mean?

Comment: See my answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is you do not find it for the same reason you will (I think) not find the following words and expressions either:

> Underview
>   Underall
>   It's all under the place
>   Underseer
>   Game under!

The explanation being that "under"is not always the antonym of "over".

In the same way, you won't find:

> Something is over investigation

Comment: You're right (and mplungjan was also right), I translated from Dutch to literally, I should have used "overhaul".

Answer (score 2):

Probably because there is insufficient evidence for its use.

Comment: According to [innersting.blogspot](http://innersting.blogspot.co.uk/2011/10/lasterday-operationing-was-so-terrible.html) 'underhaul' is a member of "words and sayings that people make up and mangle.... You hear them everyday!" Though this seems to confer 'word status' on it, something I'd contest.

Answer (score 0):

Converting my comment to an answer

Sounds like a direct syllable translation from the Dutch ***Onderhoud*** - I have only ever heard of overhaul which may match translation of this word

***Overhaul***
nounˈōvərˌhôl/

> a thorough examination of machinery or a system, with repairs or changes made if necessary.

Where as the ACTUAL translation of ***Onderhoud*** is ***Maintenance***

> the process of maintaining or preserving someone or something, or the state of being maintained.